# leetcode: render log files, not able to sort

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

Here is the [discussion](https://leetcode.com/problems/reorder-log-files/discuss/193656/C%2B%2B-stable_sort-easy-to-understand) for [question](https://leetcode.com/problems/reorder-log-files/).

I tried to convert the following c++ answers (from discussion above) to javascript.

```
static bool myCompare(string a, string b){
        int i = a.find(' ');
        int j = b.find(' ');
        if(isdigit(a[i + 1]))
            if(isdigit(b[j + 1]))
                return false;       // a b are both digit logs, a == b, keep their original order
            else
                return false;       // a is digit log, b is letter log, a > b
        else
            if(isdigit(b[j + 1]))
                return true;        // a is letter log, b is digit log, a < b
            else {
                if (a.substr(i) == b.substr(j))
                    return a.substr(0,i) < b.substr(0,j); //If string part is the same, compare key
                else
                    return a.substr(i) < b.substr(j);   // a and b are both letter
            }
    }

    vector<string> reorderLogFiles(vector<string>& logs) {
        //The order of equal elements is guaranteed to be preserved in stable_sort.
        //Use sort() cannot pass the OJ. 
        stable_sort(logs.begin(), logs.end(), myCompare);
        return logs;
    }
```

My solution is followed:

```
var reorderLogFiles = function(logs) {
    return logs.sort(cmp);
}

var cmp = function(a, b) {
    let i = a.indexOf(' ');
    let j = b.indexOf(' ');

    if(isdigit(a[i + 1])) {
        if(isdigit(b[j + 1])) {
            // a, b digit, a == b
            return 0;
        } else {
            // a digit, b letter, b|a
            return 1;
        }
    } else {
        let condi;

        // a letter, b digit, a|b
        if(isdigit(b[j + 1])) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            // both letter
            if (a.substring(i+1) === b.substring(j+1)) {
                // start from space, all same, compare key
                condi = a.substring(0,i).localeCompare(b.substring(0,j));                
                //console.log('same', condi, a.substring(0,i), b.substring(0,j));

                return condi;
            } else {    
                condi = a.substring(i+1).localeCompare(b.substring(j+1));

                //console.log('not same', condi, a.substring(i+1), ' | ', b.substring(j+1));

                return condi;
            }
        }
    }

}

var isdigit = function(letter) {
    if(!isNaN(letter)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Input:

```
["6p tzwmh ige mc", "ns 566543603829", "ubd cujg j d yf", "ha6 1 938 376 5", "3yx 97 666 56 5", "d 84 34353 2249", "0 tllgmf qp znc", "s 1088746413789", "ys0 splqqxoflgx", "uhb rfrwt qzx r", "u lrvmdt ykmox", "ah4 4209164350", "rap 7729 8 125", "4 nivgc qo z i", "apx 814023338 8"]
```

My output:

```
["ubd cujg j d yf","u lrvmdt ykmox","4 nivgc qo z i","uhb rfrwt qzx r","ys0 splqqxoflgx","0 tllgmf qp znc","6p tzwmh ige mc","ns 566543603829","ha6 1 938 376 5","3yx 97 666 56 5","d 84 34353 2249","ah4 4209164350","rap 7729 8 125","apx 814023338 8","s 1088746413789"]
```

Expected:

```
["ubd cujg j d yf","u lrvmdt ykmox","4 nivgc qo z i","uhb rfrwt qzx r","ys0 splqqxoflgx","0 tllgmf qp znc","6p tzwmh ige mc","ns 566543603829","ha6 1 938 376 5","3yx 97 666 56 5","d 84 34353 2249","s 1088746413789","ah4 4209164350","rap 7729 8 125","apx 814023338 8"]
```

Diff between my output and expected output:

`"s 1088746413789"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** achieve **stable sort** in javascript just by passing **0** when there are other strings being compared to returning other values than `0`. You will have to store it's indexes in a map and then judge accordingly. I have modified your code as below:

```
var map = {};

var reorderLogFiles = function(logs) {
    logs.forEach(function(value,index){
        map[value] = index;
    });
    return logs.sort(cmp);
}

var cmp = function(a, b) {
    let i = a.trim().indexOf(' ');
    let j = b.trim().indexOf(' ');
    if(isDigit(a[i+1])){
        if(isDigit(b[j+1])) return map[a] - map[b];
        return 1;
    }

    if(isDigit(b[j+1])){
        return -1;
    }

    let cond = a.substring(i+1).localeCompare(b.substring(j+1));
    if(cond == 0) return a.substring(0,i).localeCompare(b.substring(0,j));
    return cond;
}

var isDigit = function(letter) {
    return !isNaN(letter);
}
```

- First, we create a map of strings with it's occurrence indexes.
- Later, we use to decide when both `a` and `b` are digit logs.
- If both are letter logs, then compare the logs ignoring identifier.
- Use the identifier in case of clash.

Your code has an issue such as below:

```
// both letter
            if (a.substring(i+1) === b.substring(j+1)) {
                // start from space, all same, compare key
                condi = a.substring(0,i).localeCompare(b.substring(0,j));                
                //console.log('same', condi, a.substring(0,i), b.substring(0,j));

                return condi;
            } else {    
                condi = a.substring(i+1).localeCompare(b.substring(j+1));

                //console.log('not same', condi, a.substring(i+1), ' | ', b.substring(j+1));

                return condi;
            }
```

- Here, you are comparing the letter logs ignoring the identifier. But let's say both are same(in a tie situation), you aren't checking for lexicographical ordering with their identifiers. Also, first letter character match also doesn't work for the usual case.
- **Best way** to solve this problem is to collect letter logs and digit logs in different arrays and then sort only letter logs and append digit logs in the end. This would give you a better average case performance if many logs are digit logs on a good number of tests.